# add tabs to user's facebook page through facebook api

Tags: facebook

Can a facebook api add tabs to users' facebook page, if yes then HOW??

Comment: See code snippet at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7633372/356060

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a tab to you application by filling profile tab part in facebook integration

how to go there

http://www.facebook.com/developers/

choose the application (if you have any) --> edit settings --> facebook integration

then fill tab profile.

unfortunately , profile tabs will no longer be allowed see [this link.](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/415)

Comment: User profile tabs are being withdrawn, but Brand pages (eg http://www.facebook.com/SonyEricssonUK) will still be able to use profile tabs. From what one of the Facebook guys said at a recent Developer Garage in London, this is so that they can increase the functionality available to FBML tabs without worrying about the security impact on user pages.

Comment: so who says that is a Brand Page or not

Answer (score 1):

you can't add tabs to a users profile page, it has to be the user who adds them.

However, you can add a link to make the process easier, see [Add Profile Tab](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/372) from Facebook developer blog.

Comment: sorry, but I found that fb api can make it's own tab while setting up the api on the facebook site, please confirm or illustrate what did you mean??