# How to remove FaceBook page tab via api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been banging my head over this for hours now... and can't seem to be able to remove a facebook page tab via api. The access token used has all of the following permissions "offline_access,publish_stream,manage_pages,publish_actions"

I've tried to make a call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[page id]/tabs/app_[app_id]?method=delete&access_token=[access token]
```

the response is

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#210) Subject must be a page.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 210
   }
}
```

---

if i use the the facebook graph explorer

```
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
```

the response is the tab object json... doesn't remove

---

if i do javascript api call

```
        FB.api(**pageid/tabs/app_1234**, 'delete', {access_token: **My Access tocken**}  ,function(response) {
            alert(response);
        });
```

the response is **(#210) Subject must be a page.**

---

I've read that if you include the full pagid/tabs/tabid then it becomes /paigeid/tabs/pagaid/tabs/tabid   so i've tried

```
        FB.api(**app_1234**, 'delete', {access_token: **My Access tocken**}  ,function(response) {
            alert(response);
        });
```

the response is

```
(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: app_XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

---

if i use the C# facebook client

```
fc.Delete( "pageid/tabs/tabid")
```

the result is again

```
 (#210) Subject must be a page.
```

Comment: of course i will... lol. i was just tabbed out of page trying to still find a solution by myself. There ya go.  And ty btw... i also found this that helped..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444110/fetching-pages-tab-and-adding-tab-to-the-facebook-pages-by-graph-api-method-fb

Comment: i also accepted over half of my questions that i answered myself... what a champ i am :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message seems to be confusing. I have also come across this problem in past.

You are not using the correct access_token. Use access_token for page.